# Error in the last line of my PHP mail() script unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, email

Here is the php code itself.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["First"];
$Last_name = $_POST["Last"];
$Age = $_POST["Age"];
$Height = $_POST["Height"];
$Weight = $_POST["Weight"];
$Eye_Color = $_POST["Eye"];
$Hair = $_POST["Hair"];
$Glasses_or_Contacts = $_POST["Glasses_or_Contacts"];
$Customer_Email = $_POST["Contact_Email"];

$email_from ='WEBMASTEREMAIL@gmail.com';
$email_subject = "Form completion Email";
$email_body = "$name, $Last_name, $Age, $Height, $Weight $Eye_Color, $Hair, $Glasses_or_Contacts, $Customer_Email";

$to = 'MYEMAIL0@gmail.com, WEBMASTEREMAIL@gmail.com'


mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,);

?>
```

I removed my emails with caps MYEMAIL and WEBMASTEREMAIL any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$to = 'MYEMAIL0@gmail.com, WEBMASTEREMAIL@gmail.com'` needs its final line terminator `;`

Comment: and the last parameter of the `mail` function call is missing

Comment: @Scuzzy added the semi but now it gives me an error of unexpected ')'on the last line. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @sebas Im kinda of new to php what "call" do you mean in the last parameter?

Comment: @Sebas i fixed it, I think, i didnt recive an error after removing the , in the last part of mail. Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you haven't closed off the `$to` variable.
Set that to:

```
$to = 'MYEMAIL0@gmail.com, WEBMASTEREMAIL@gmail.com';
```

And change your `mail()` function to:

```
if(!mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body)) {
    echo 'failed';
} else {
    echo 'sent';
}
```

You would get an error on the `mail()` line because you had one too many commas (`,`).

---

**NOTE**

The fourth **`4`** parameter is for your headers. (<sup>*You didn't include that in your script. So I didn't add them, you can read the [`mail()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to learn how to add them.*</sup>)

Comment: let him  remove his question ,delete your answer :D

Comment: Thanks @Darren that seemed to be the fix i was looking for.